# Getting error messages from psycopg2 exceptions

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

This is my first project using psycopg2 extensively. I'm trying to find a way to extract the psql error message for whenever a connection attempt fails. I've tested the code below will work if all the variables are set correctly, however whenever an error condition occurs (e.g. user chooses a database that doesn't exist), Python will give me the following:

```
I am unable to connect to the database
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./duplicate_finder.py", line 163, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./duplicate_finder.py", line 142, in main
    print e.diag.message_detail
AttributeError: 'OperationalError' object has no attribute 'diag'
```

Is there a simple, catch-all method to catch whatever error message psql generates when a connection fails, or do I need to write except blocks for multiple psycopg2 exceptions?

Extract from my script:

```
import sys, getopt, os, time, csv, psycopg2

    ...
    ...

    conn_string = "host=" + dbhost + " dbname=" + database + " user=" + dbuser + " password=" + dbpass
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        print "Unable to connect!"
        print e.pgerror
        print e.diag.message_detail
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print "Connected!"
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT id, lastname, firstname, location FROM test ORDER BY ctl_upd_dttm DESC;")
        print cur.fetchone()
        ...
        conn.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are catching all exceptions with the base class `psycopg2.Error`. Your problem is probably that the `diag` attribute is new in `psycopg2 2.5`. What is your version?

```
>>> print psycopg2.__version__
2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)
```

Comment: >>> import psycopg2
>>> print psycopg2.__version__
2.0.14 (dt dec ext pq3)

Looks like I'm a few versions behind. Unfortunately, looks like that's the most up-to-date version according to my distro's (Scientific Linux) repos + epel. Might have to go the source route with this . . .

Comment: Just curious, before I embark on a potentially hazardous quest of manually upgrading psycopg2, is there a way to get the psql connect error messages in older versions of psycopg2, or am I stuck with just giving them a generic message when something goes wrong?

Comment: @sirjames2004 I don't know. But installing with `setup` or `pip` is quite easy: http://initd.org/psycopg/install/. Just remember to `yum remove psycopg2` first.

Comment: @sirjames2004 And you need Python 2.5+ for psycopg 2.5

Answer (score 33):

When I try to catch exceptions, e.pgerror is always None for connection errors. The following code block gets around this by directly printing 'e'.

```
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
except psycopg2.OperationalError as e:
    print('Unable to connect!\n{0}').format(e)
    sys.exit(1)
else:
   print('Connected!')
   # do stuff
```

For example, in the case of password authentication failure:

```
Unable to connect!
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user"
```

I realize this question is a year old but hopefully might help someone in the future

Answer (score 9):

Ended up here because of

> class 'psycopg2.errors.InvalidCursorName'

on Django. If that's your case, be sure to makemigrations

Answer (score 2):

Since Python 3.9 ([`.removesuffix()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix), [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings)) I use

```py
except psycopg2.Error as e:
  log.error(f"{type(e).__module__.removesuffix('.errors')}:{type(e).__name__}: {str(e).rstrip()}")
  if conn: conn.rollback()
```

where `log` is [logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330317/print-timestamp-for-logging-in-python/28330410#28330410).

Connection errors lives directly in psycopg2 module while syntax errors in psycopg2.errors submodule. There is an [unwanted newline](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/584) at the end of every psycopg2 error message.