# Print timestamp for logging in Python

Tags: python

I want to print the current timestamp, when an event succeeded or not in my python script.
By only adding...

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

.... at the beginning of each line, te same date appears in every line

```
[INFO] 04.Feb 2015 20:49:41: cl1
[ OK ] 04.Feb 2015 20:49:41: 8.8.8.8 ONLINE!
[INFO] 04.Feb 2015 20:49:41: cl2
[ OK ] 04.Feb 2015 20:49:41: 8.8.8.8 ONLINE!
[INFO] 04.Feb 2015 20:49:41: cl3
[ OK ] 04.Feb 2015 20:49:41: 8.8.8.8 ONLINE!
```

(I added `time.sleep(5)`in between)

My next idea was to create a function, calling the current time, but i'm failing at embedding this function to the `print`command.

> File rs.py

```
OK =   "[" + bc.OKGREEN + " OK "  + bc.ENDC + "] " + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%b %Y %H:%M:%S")
INFO = "[" + bc.OKBLUE  + "INFO"  + bc.ENDC + "] " + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%b %Y %H:%M:%S")
WARN = "[" + bc.WARN    + "WARN"  + bc.ENDC + "] " + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%b %Y %H:%M:%S")
ERR =  "[" + bc.ERR     + "FAIL"  + bc.ENDC + "] " + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%b %Y %H:%M:%S")
DEB =  "[" + bc.HEADER  + "DEBUG" + bc.ENDC + "] " + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

> File myapp.py

```
import rs # importing rs.py

print rs.OK + hostname + "is up!"
time.sleep(3)
print rs.ERR+ hostname + "is down!"
```

Is printing:

```
>>> [INFO] 04.Feb 2015 20:49:41: xxx is up!
>>> [ERR ] 04.Feb 2015 20:49:41: xxx is down!
```

Answer (score 312, accepted):

Before the first time you log anything do this:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO,
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Example on the REPL:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(
...         format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
...         level=logging.INFO,
...         datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> 
>>> logging.info('an info messge')
2017-05-25 00:58:28 INFO     an info messge
>>> logging.debug('a debug messag is not shown')
>>>
```

Comment: Documentation on how to use logging: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

Comment: [format options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes)

Comment: This modifies the root logger which can have unforseen consequences. 

@paidhima's answer is preferable for this reason.

Answer (score 75):

Something like below would do:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                              datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Have a look at the `logging` module for Python.  You don't need to mess about with creating your own date, just let the logging module do it for you.  That formatter object can be applied to a logging handler so you can just log with `logger.info('This is an info message.')`. No print statements required.

Here's a boilerplate procedure I use:

```
import logging
import sys

def setup_custom_logger(name):
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                                  datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    handler = logging.FileHandler('log.txt', mode='w')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    screen_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    screen_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.addHandler(screen_handler)
    return logger

>>> logger = setup_custom_logger('myapp')
>>> logger.info('This is a message!')
2015-02-04 15:07:12 INFO     This is a message!
>>> logger.error('Here is another')
2015-02-04 15:07:30 ERROR    Here is another
```

Comment: without the "datefmt', how would the formatter display the timestamp? I have a project where no date format is mentioned, I need to read logs and I see the timestamp as a 10 digit value like "0063730209" How should I read it as a real human understandable date? I have to right to edit the Logger. EPOCH convertor shows the time as a date in 1972 which is definitely an invalid and incorrect value. Any suggestions how I can read the timestamp present in my log file?

Comment: It is possible to use the _modern_ [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings)-like **style** specification:
```logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, style='{', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', format='{asctime} {levelname} {filename}:{lineno}: {message}')```

Comment: Thanks @HansGinzel for the idea of using that syntax... Wasn't aware of `style='{'` as a valid parameter. It looks odd at first :) And you included `{filename}:{lineno}:` which is a nice touch

Comment: Hey @paidhima, can I check with you, if it want to append that print statement to my log.txt in the same format how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The datetime is calculated when the string is formed. So in your case, only once at the initialisation. Instead, you should do something like this:

```
def ok(hostname=None, status=None):
    output = (
        "[" + bc.OKGREEN + " OK "  + bc.ENDC + "] " +
        datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%b %Y %H:%M:%S")
    )
    if hostname is not None:
        output += ' ' + hostname
    if status is not None:
        output += ' ' + status
    print output
```

To log, just do use `ok()` which will reevaluate the datetime each time.

Note that @paidhima suggestion is also good.

Comment: Can i print this function besides a text output like `print ok() + Started!` or do i have to edit the function so that `ok("Started!")` prints `[ OK ] 2015-03-02 ... Started!`?

Comment: @HerrAusragend I updated my answer to match your needs. Putting everything in the function that prints into the log is a good idea if you want to keep all the logging logic into one function. If not, the function could return a string instead of printing and then you can do whatever you want with the string.